# How to use $ in PHP SQL Query?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

i have to use V$session table in php , kindly any one help me on this

EX: "select * from V$session " in this case i am getting error in PHP like the below due to $ symbol,

**Undefined variable**

Thanks 
William R

Comment: Don't enclose V$session in double quotes ("), use single quotes (')

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape `$` characters in PHP strings if you want a literal `$` instead of a *start of variable*.

Answer (score 0):

just use single quotes instead of double quotes. variables are dereferenced if they are inside double quotes.